# Assign to NSString after alloc/init

Tags: objective-c

This doesn't seem to work:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
string = @"%@M", anotherstring;
```

I expect this to make "string" equal to "5M" if "anotherstring" is "5".

Is this not the right syntax? Now, I could use initWithFormat and it would work, but how can you separate it into two different lines and also work?

Comment: Why would you want to separate the code into two lines? You can make it work, but there's no real reason to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code. Firstly, `NSString`s are immutable, and once you allocate and initialize them, they're set, and there's no way to change them. For that, you'd have to look into `NSMutableString`.

Secondly, the syntax of your code makes no sense. `@"%@M", anotherString` is not a valid Objective-C method call. You are indeed looking for `-initWithFormat:` to perform the operation you want. The code should look like this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@M", anotherString];
```

---

Read more about `NSString` and how to use it in the [NSString Programming Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) document, and the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i) to get a sense of how to work with strings in Cocoa and Objective-C.

Comment: Actually, `@"%@M", anotherString` _is_ valid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: @Wilbur, yes you're right. I know it's valid code, but not in the sense that andrewjs is looking for. I will change my answer to reflect as such ('valid Objective-C code' -> 'a valid Objective-C method call').

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
string = @"%@M", anotherstring;
```

is syntactically correct, but it doesn't do what you want it to do. This is how you format a string:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@M", anotherstring];
```

There's no point in separating it into two lines. This:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@M", anotherstring];
```

will create an extra `NSString` object, and also cause a memory leak.

Comment: But what if there are times when you need to re-assign the value of the string? release it first, then re-assign? Or what if you wanted to create the string, then have its string contents depend on an IF statement? you'd need to separate the INIT into a different line than the string contents

Comment: @andrewjs: In the first case, yes, you'd have to release and reassign. In the second, you could just declare the variable, but not initialize it, like so: `NSString *s; if (someCondition) { s = @"true"; } else { s = @"false"; }`.

Comment: i assume that for your statement `s=@"true";` you would add the alloc/init code inside that part of the `if` statement? your suggestion leaves out the alloc/init completely; i'd imagine that's a problem.

Comment: @andrewjs: No, you can initialize strings using `s = @"true";`. You only *need* `NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] init];` if you really just want an empty string (that's all the default constructor does), but if you just want an empty string you might as well do `NSString *s = @"";` anyway. Or just skip the initialization altogether until you know what you actually want the value of the string to be.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
NSString* string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@M", anotherString];
```

Keep in mind that the `=` operator is assignment. Any time you use it, any value was stored in your variable is overwritten with the new one. So even if your original code was syntactically correct it still has faulty semantics that would, in this case, cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

just make it into a property and you dont need to worry about releasing and retaining the "string" (that is if you autocreate it by using  synthesize). and dont forget to autorelease the object ur assigning to the property:

self.string = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]